# Writing script to find all PID of processes of user

Tags: bash

I really want to use     `ps -aux` to get this.
So I wrote script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
        echo -n "No arguments were written"
        read uid
else
        uid=$1
fi
procesy=`ps -aux | awk '{if ($1=="$uid") print$2}'`
echo $procesy
```

Why it is not working ?
When I am writinig `./script root` I am getting nothing but blank line.

Comment: Another FAQ: Read about how to pass variables in `awk`.

Comment: Check your man page. `ps` should already have an option to output just the process IDs, without having to filter them out of the full output of `ps -aux`.

Comment: For the people who wants to close the question, the question isn't about how to use `awk` if you have a solution that doesn't use `awk` feel free to add.

Comment: @devnull are you saying that this answer could be answered only using `awk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script you have a problem using a shell variable inside `awk`. The right way using `awk` should be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
        echo -n "No arguments were written"
        read user
else
        user=$1
fi
procesy=`ps aux | awk -v usr=$user '{if ($1==usr) print$2}'`
echo $procesy
```

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Because this was about in the question.But I am aware that l0b0's  [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21308393/2353900) is better.

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you need:

```
pgrep -U $1
```